Why does KCL not work in the ideal non-inverting op amp output node?
I have a simple ideal non-inverting op-amp pictured below:

If I take KCL at the inverting terminal, I get (Vs - 0)/(R1) + (vs - Vo)/(R2) = 0. This gives me the proper equation of Vo = (1 + (R2/R1))(Vs). I want to understand WHY I can't apply this at node Vo. Since it's an "ideal" op-amp, no current flows through the negative terminal, so from Vo's perspective, it is one current with R1 and R2 in series. I get the equation (Vo - (Vs-0))/(R1+R2) = 0. Obviously not correct, but I want to understand why? Again, KCL would lead me to believe Vo sees this as one current.
So, my two main questions are:

Can we apply a KCL equation at the output node, and if not,
Why can we apply KCL at the negative terminal but not the output terminal?


KCL holds at the output terminal, like at any other node. However, a KCL equation at this node is not terribly informative and generally doesn't help advance the process of nodal analysis in practice.
If we were to form a KCL equation for this circuit at the op amp output node, we would say that the sum of R2's rightward current, the output current coming from the op amp pin, and whatever current might be flowing into the node from the (un-drawn, unspecified) circuit downstream of the op amp, must all sum to zero.
This has one particularly pesky unknown: The op amp output current, which (for an ideal op amp) is entirely unspecified at early stages of solving the problem. Unlike a resistor (whose branch equation is Ohm's Law), the equations describing an ideal op amp discuss voltages, but say nothing about this current.
You hence end up with a KCL equation which (if done correctly) is physically true, but doesn't help you solve the circuit. On the other hand, once you've solved for the output voltage and other currents through other means, this KCL equation would let you predict the output current that the op amp is expected to sink or source. This is then helpful to evaluate power consumption or whether a certain physical op amp is capable of driving enough current to physically realize your circuit.

Why can we apply KCL at the negative terminal but not the output terminal?

At the negative terminal, we have an estimate for the current going into the op amp pin. It's either 0 in the simplest approximation, or a small value based on input bias current and input impedance if we have a non-ideal op amp.
